# Generic error occurred in GDI+ when disposing the bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

My code:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(filePath);
...
bitmap.Dispose();   <---  Fails here
```

Out of 30k images in a folder (remote UNC share) , it failed on 2 files with the `Generic error occurred in GDI+` when calling `.Dispose`.

What are some of the reasons this could happen?

Comment: GDI objects limit? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/gdi-objects)

Comment: @vik_78 Wouldn't the object limit failure occur at the creation of the object rather than it's disposal?

Comment: Does it always fail on only those two images? They may be corrupt.

Comment: @DourHighArch No.  Usually it's random files.  I thought that it might be a network disconnection, but the code above is in an algorithm running many threads in parallel - there would be more failures if that happened.

Comment: Are you running a desktop app or a server/service?

Comment: Suspicious: `...`

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's running on the Windows Server 2016 x64 as a Windows Service.

Comment: I'll bring the files locally to the server and run it to make sure it's not the network connection that's messing things up.

Comment: You [shouldn't be using GDI+ on a server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).  I got burned that way once. Code could run forever on a desktop, failed within hours on a server.

Comment: And forget about that WIC alternative.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What do u by forget WIC?  That's what they are recommending in the link u provided?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am not sure what I could use instead.  The library I am using is needing the System.Drawing.Bitmap as a parameter (which I why I am newing it up to begin with).

Comment: Re Wic: try to find it. It's all C++, and pretty old and stale.

Comment: I ended up using ImageSharp, despite its perpetual beta status. But there are more alternatives, look around. Don't use the WPF controls.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks, but it probably won't work for me.  I am utilizing [nQuant](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=nquant) library which needs System.Drawing.  On the original link provided, it states that System.Drawing could cause instability - doesn't say why or what specific operations.  So far, with the exception of these occasional GDI+ errors, everything has been running smoothly with no impact  on other applications on the box.  I guess will keep on eye on it until i come up with a better solution.

Comment: You might take a look at system.drawing.common, but I never saw a statement about the use on a server.